# MATLAB ode45 function 'Too many inputs error'

Tags: matlab, syntax, equations, ode45

My function is:

```
function [tout, yout] = Lorenz (rho, x0)
%define constants
sigma = 10;
beta = 8/3;

%initial conditions
y0 = [x0; 1; 0];

f = @(t, y) [sigma*(y(2)-y(1)); (y(1)*(rho-y(3)))-y(2); (y(1)*y(2)) - (beta*y(3))];

[tout, yout] = ode45(f, [0 100], y0, 'RelTol', 1e-6, 'AbsTol', 1e-8);
end
```

When I run the function in the command window with

```
Lorenz(14,0)
```

I return

```
Error using Lorenz>@(t,y)[sigma*(y(2)-y(1));(y(1)*(rho-y(3)))-y(2);(y(1)*y(2))-(beta*y(3))]
Too many input arguments.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the syntax is not officially [documented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) by MathWorks, the ODE suite does accept the syntax:

```
[t,y] = ode45(odefun,tspan,y0,options,extra1,extra2,...);
```

where `options` should be a `struct` created by [`odeset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) (not falling inline with the name-value system of other functions) and `extra1,extra2,...` is any number of extra, solve-constant parameters to be passed to `odefun`.  I imagine it's a hold over from before anonymous functions possessed their own workspace to allow creation-time [function parametrization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html).

So, since the options you're passing are not part of a `struct`, `ode45` takes the syntax to be

```
[t,y] = ode45(odefun,tspan,y0,extra1,extra2,extra3,extra4);
```

and, via `feval`, will make the call `odefun(t,y,extra1,extra2,extra3,extra4)`. A minor rewrite using `odeset` should do the job nicely:

```
options      = odeset('RelTol', 1e-6, 'AbsTol', 1e-8);
[tout, yout] = ode45(f, [0 100], y0, options);
```

Comment: It's a holdover from before anonymous functions even existed in Matlab.